# Angularjs: ng-change for select list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angularjs, I have a directive which shows list of questions. I intend to do some logic when `selectedQuestion` changes. So, I used `ng-change`.

This is my directive:

```
 restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {                             
                selectedQuestion: '=?', 
                questionsList: '='  
            },
            link: function (scope) {
                scope.change = function () {
                    if (scope.selectedQuestion) {
                        //do something
                    }
                };
            }
```

This is the html template for my directive:

```
   <select  ng-model="selectedQuestion"
            ng-options="avail.question for avail in questionsList track by avail.id" ng-change="change()"
   </select>

  {{selectedQuestion}}
```

When I change the question in the UI list, the `{{selectedQuestion}}` changes to show the json of the question selected. However the `scope.selectedQuestion` in  `scope.change` function is always the same as initialized (not changing).

What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try passing model as parameter to the `ng-change` function:

```
<select ng-model="selectedQuestion"
        ng-options="avail.question for avail in questionsList track by avail.id" 
        ng-change="change(selectedQuestion)"
</select>
```

Then in your directive:

```
link: function (scope) {
        scope.change = function (currentQuestion) {
            if (currentQuestion) {
            }
        };
     }
```